# Adding spectral values of Sentinel-2 to table with coordinates (20k points) giving error

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am trying to export an excel sheet with spectral values from Google Earth Engine (Sentinel-2) to my Google Drive. I am using the Python API from my google colab page but I can not get the geemap.extract_values_to_points to work. I even tried the code in the JavaScript code editor (in JavaScript, not Python) and it didn't work there either.

I have tried everything I can find on Google API Docs, StackOverflow, and GIS StackExchange - nothing has worked for me. Everytime I try I receive this error message:

> EEException: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 4194304 bytes.

Eventually I need to iterate over all the 20000 points in Europe so that I can extract all the spectral values but to keep it simple for initial export here is my code for a single image:

```
# For more information regarding this section please visit the website below
# https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S

# Load a feature collection.
## featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
# Filter the collection.
# filteredFC = featureCollection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Europe'))
filteredFC = featureCollection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('wld_rgn', 'Europe'))

#Initiate map to check results
Map = geemap.Map(center=[52,5], zoom=10, layer_ctrl=True)
Map

# insert required period of time
point = ee.Geometry.Polygon(filteredFC)
start = ee.Date('2019-05-01')
finish = ee.Date('2020-06-01')

# Google Earth engine settings
collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR") \
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than', 20) \
    .filterDate(start, finish) \
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER', True) \
    #.filterBounds(filteredFC)

# Compute the median in each band, each pixel.
# Band names are B1_median, B2_median, etc.
median = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
clipped = median.clip(filteredFC)
clipped = clipped.reproject(clipped.projection(), scale = 60)

# The output is an Image.  Add it to the map.
vis_param = {'bands': ['B4_median', 'B3_median', 'B2_median'], 'min': 0, 'max': 2000,}
Map.addLayer(clipped, vis_param)

# import geojson shapefile to geemap
#in_shp = 'LUCAS_TOPSOIL_2015.geojson'
in_fc = geemap.shp_to_ee('coordinates.shp')
#Map.add_geojson(in_shp, 'Points')
Map

# read csv file to which spectral information will be added
out_csv = 'coordinates_with_spectral_values.csv'

#extract the spectral information and add to csv file
geemap.extract_values_to_points(in_fc, clipped, out_csv)
```

So I first create my Sentinel-2 image using the Google Earth Engine API. I then load the points into the same map. The last step however, to add spectral information of the bands does not seem to work to to the EEException error. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use clip with a (big) feature collection, use clipToCollection.

But your main problem is probably that the "coordinates.shp" file is probably being inlined in the call to extract the values and that table it too large to use that way.  Upload the file as an asset first.